# window.onclick return Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, onclick

Need Help. When I execute `window.onclick`, it return `Cannot read property 'style' of null` on browser consol log. did i missed something?

This's HTML Code.

```
<div id="toolIcon" onclick='document.getElementById("toolCont").style.display = "block";'>
    Show Menu
</div>

<div class="msgTextTop" id="streamHead">
    <!-- Respond AJAX here -->          
</div>
```

This's PHP Code that will send via AJAX.

```
echo "  <div class='msgTopTool_cont' id='toolCont'>";
echo "      <div class='toolContGroup'>";
echo "          <ul class='tolContUL'>";
echo "              <li class='tolContLI'><a href='profile.php?uid=" . $qFC['ID'] . "'>View Profile</a></li>";
echo "              <li class='tolContLI'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Second Link</a></li>";
echo "          </ul>";
echo "      </div>";
echo "      <div class='toolContGroup'>";
echo "          <ul class='tolContUL'>";
echo "              <li class='tolContLI'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Third Link</a></li>";
echo "          </ul>";
echo "      </div>";
echo "  </div>";
```

Thi's AJAX respond.

```
function clickbutton() {
    //AJAX Code status
        document.getElementById('streamHead').innerHTML = this.responseText;
    //AJAX Code send
}
```

This's Javascript Code.

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('#toolIcon')) { //toolIcon is a button to show 'toolCont'
        document.getElementById('toolCont').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Missing one closing bracket : `if (!event.target.matches('#toolCont')) {`

Comment: It seems that your `window.onclick` is triggered prior to the `innerHTML` is set hence, the error. In your case it is possible because there is a `NOT` condition which is set to true i.e. it will be true on every click till the time innerHTML is set.

Comment: I think so, but how to solve it?

Comment: @Derry - You should add the event listener after the `innerHTML` is set or adding a safe check could work.

Comment: @nikhil - Ok, I'll try..

Answer (score 0):

In you Javascript code ')' is missing after `('#toolCont')`

Please find the below code and try it.

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
   if (!event.target.matches('#toolCont')) {
      document.getElementById('toolCont').style.display = 'none';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check that element is set or not before using it. change your `window.onclick` as below

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if(document.body.contains(document.getElementById('toolCont')))
  {
    if (!event.target.matches('#toolIcon')) {
        document.getElementById('toolCont').style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: it solve the issue but I face another issue, that when I click `<div id="toolIcon" onclick='document.getElementById("toolCont").style.display = "block";'` it didn't respond

Comment: this `<div id="toolIcon" onclick='document.getElementById("toolCont").style.display = "block";'>Show Menu</div>` placed above `<div class="msgTextTop" id="streamHead">`

Answer (score 0):

`<div onclick='document.getElementById("toolCont").style.display = "block";`

> it will not respond because u have just changed the div display property to 'none' which means its no longer clickable, u first need to make its diplay back to 'block' by using javascript, not by any event listener , then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In your code a element having id "toolCont" is not defined.

```html
<div id="toolIcon" onclick='document.getElementById("toolIcon").style.color = "red";'>
    Change color
</div>

<div class="msgTextTop" id="streamHead">
    <!-- Respond AJAX here -->          
</div>

<div id="toolIcon" onclick='document.getElementById("toolIcon1").style.display = "block";'>
    Show Menu
</div>

<div class="msgTextTop" id="streamHead">
    <!-- Respond AJAX here -->          
</div>
```